# Organizing data (pandas dataframe)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data in the following form:
[image]

```
         product/productId                                         B000EVS4TY
1            product/title   Arrowhead Mills Cookie Mix, Chocolate Chip, 1...
2            product/price                                            unknown
3            review/userId                                     A2SRVDDDOQ8QJL
4       review/profileName                                            MJ23447
5       review/helpfulness                                                2/4
6             review/score                                                4.0
7              review/time                                         1206576000
8           review/summary                               Delicious cookie mix
9              review/text   I thought it was funny that I bought this pro...
10       product/productId                                         B0000DF3IX
11           product/title                            Paprika Hungarian Sweet
12           product/price                                            unknown
13           review/userId                                     A244MHL2UN2EYL
14      review/profileName                          P. J. Whiting "book cook"
15      review/helpfulness                                                0/0
16            review/score                                                5.0
17             review/time                                         1127088000
```

I want to convert it to a dataframe such that the entries in the 1st column

```
        product/productId                                         
        product/title   
       product/price                                            
        review/userId                                     
   review/profileName                                            
   review/helpfulness                                                
        review/score                                                               
        review/time                                         
       review/summary                               
          review/text
```

are the column headers with the values arranged corresponding to each header in the table.

Comment: I guess you need transpose, df.T

Comment: I could not understand if the example line you provided is stored in any file format or not? does it have any column separator character?

Comment: The data is stacked in (.txt) format (continuously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still had a tiny doubt about your file, but since both my suggestions are quite similar, I will try to address both the scenarios you might have.

In case your file doesn't actually have the line numbers inside of it, this should do it:

```
filepath = "./untitled.txt" # you need to change this to your file path
column_separator="\s{3,}" # we'll use a regex, I explain some caveats of this below...

# engine='python' surpresses a warning by pandas
# header=None is that so all lines are considered 'data'
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=column_separator, engine="python", header=None) 

df = df.set_index(0)           # this takes column '0' and uses it as the dataframe index
df = df.T                      # this makes the data look like you were asking (goes from multiple rows+1column to multiple columns+1 row)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True) # this is just so the first row starts at index  '0' instead of '1'

# you could just do the last 3 lines with:
# df = df.set_index(0).T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

If you do have line numbers, then we just need to do some little adjustments

```
filepath = "./untitled1.txt"
column_separator="\s{3,}"

df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=column_separator, engine="python", header=None, index_col=0)
df.set_index(1).T.reset_index(drop=True) #I did all the 3 steps in 1 line, for brevity
```

- **In this last case**, I would advise you change it in order to have line numbers in all of them (in the example you provided, the numbering starts at the second line, this might be an option about how you handle headers when exporting the data in whatever tool you might be using
- **Regarding the regex**, the caveat is that "\s{3,}" looks for any block of 3 consecutive whitespaces or more to determine the column separator. The problem here is that we'll depend a bit on the data to find the columns. For instance, if in any of the values just so happens to appear 3 consecutive spaces, pandas will raise an exception, since the line will have one more column than the others. One solution to this could be increasing it to any other 'appropriate' number, but then we still depend on the data (for instance, with more than 3, in your example, "review/text" would have enough spaces for the two columns to be identified)

**edit after realising what you meant by "stacked"**

Whatever "line-number scenario" you have, you'll need to make sure you always have the same number of columns for all registers and reshape the continuous dataframe with something similar to this:

```
number_of_columns = 10             # you'll need to make sure all "registers" do have the same number of columns otherwise this will break
new_shape = (-1,number_of_columns) # this tuple will mean "whatever number of lines", by 10 columns
final_df = pd.DataFrame(data = df.values.reshape(new_shape)
                    ,columns=df.columns.tolist()[:-10])
```

Again, take notice of making sure that all lines have the same number of columns (for instance, a file with just the data you provided, assuming 10 columns, wouldn't work). Also, this solution assumes all columns will have the same name.